# If I book a Eurostar ticket through SNCB, how can I attach my Eurostar Frequent Traveller details to the booking?

Tags: tickets, loyalty-programs, eurostar

When looking to book a Eurostar ticket, I discovered that it was cheaper (for this one journey - no promises in general!) to book it via the [SNCB English website](https://www.b-europe.co.uk/Travel) rather than via Eurostar themselves. So, having double checked the numbers (including credit card fees, also lower with SNCB), I opted to book my ticket on the SNCB website.

However, at no point in the booking process did I spot anywhere to enter my Eurostar Frequent Traveller details. Now I've booked, I can't see how to change it on the SNCB site. If I go to the Eurostar site and do Manage My Booking, it shows the details of the trip, but doesn't let me change anything, so I can't therefore enter my Eurostar Frequent Traveller details there.

The worst case is that after the trip, I can log into the Eurostar website, and do a missing points claim with the ticket details. However, that's a bit of a faff, and I need to remember to do it, no sooner than 1 day after the trip ends, and no later than 3 months. Given that, I'd rather enter the details now while I'm thinking of it!

So, is it possible to attach Eurostar Frequent Traveller details to a booking made via SNCB, or is my only option the missing points claim later (assuming I remember....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [drat pointed out in his answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/25491/26), it is actually possible to specify your Eurostar Frequent Traveller number when booking through SNCB, but you must do it at the start! (Most schemes prompt for it towards the end, which caught me out)

If you have booked your ticket without your Eurostar Frequent Traveller number, there are two options available. One is to wait until a few days after you travel, then put in a retrospective claim. The second, which I've just discovered, is go to the Eurostar website and do a "Contact Us" for "Already Have A Booking" then "Frequent Traveller". Let them know the booking reference (for an SNCB reservation you need the PNR not the DNR), along with your Eurostar Frequent Traveller membership number, and they'll add it to the booking for you!

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to your statement, you can add the number during the booking process. When you book from [SNCB](https://www.b-europe.co.uk/Travel) you can tick Loyalty cards.

[image]

In the second step you can then add the Eurostar Frequent Traveller number:

[image]

I know this doesn't help you anymore since you already booked it, but this is how you can add your frequent traveller number.

Comment: Doh, completely missed that on the first page, I was looking for it later on...