# Specifying a Eurostar or SNCF frequent traveller number when booking through Loco2?

Tags: trains, online-resources, loyalty-programs, sncf

Following the help [given in this Travel.SE answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/25491/26), I now know the trick for specifying my Eurostar or SNCF frequent traveller number when booking a ticket through the SNCB website. Now, I find myself with the same problem with [Loco2](http://loco2.com/)

The Loco2 homepage is very good at asking you about any railcards you might have, and offering discounts on them, so it's good in that regard:

[image: Loco2 railcards]

Despite that, I can't seem to spot anywhere during the train selection or booking process where I can add a Eurostar Frequent Traveller or [SNCF Voyager](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27151/how-does-the-sncf-voyageur-program-work) number. Is it possible to do so, and if so, what's the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not currently possible to collect Eurostar loyalty points on Loco2. Eurostar bookings made via Loco2 are eligible to accrue points which can be added to your account after booking by quoting your PNR reference to Eurostar's customer care centre.

Disclaimer: I am a founder of Loco2

Comment: What about for SNCF Voyageur - Is there a way to get credit for those through SNCF by giving them the ticket details somehow?