# Can I earn SNCF Voyager points, for a booking made without the membership number?

Tags: trains, france, loyalty-programs, high-speed-rail, sncf

Having now [worked out what the SNCF Voyageur program is](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/27151/26), I've gone ahead and joined it, as I've a number of TGV journeys coming up in the coming months.

The slight wrinkle is that most of these TGV tickets have already been purchased, and none of them have my Voyageur membership number on them. (Some were booked before I joined, some were booked after but with sites that [don't seem to support entering them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/27524/26)).

With Eurostar, if you log into your Frequent Traveller account, then after travel you can enter the ticket details and get the credit for the travel. With most airlines, you can log into your frequent flyer account in advance, and attach your membership details to the booking.

Despite that, try as I might, I can't seem to find how to do one or the other when logged into my SNCF Voyageur account.

Is it possible to credit tickets booked without your SNCF Voyageur membership number, but travelled after joining, to your Voyageur account? And if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, it does not seem possible to update your ticket with a membership card number after buying the ticket.

On the [help of voyages-sncf.com](http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/toute-laide-train/je-prepare-mon-voyage/programmes-de-fidelite/cumuler-des-points-avantages-sur-ma-carte-de-fidelite){french}, the question is answered with the suggestion to exchange your current ticket for a new one, mentioning your membership number. My opinion is that it is worth only if you can cancel your ticket for free (ticket "Loisirs" and "Loisirs Jeune" and "Pro" are usually cancellable without a fee) and get a new one for the same price or a very close price. So you can check the current price of the ticket you would like to exchange and figure if this is worth it.

Note that after the trip, it is not possible at all to associate this number to your ticket.

Comment: Argh, I was just trying to figure this out myself, but it seems you're right. More annoying is that I had the membership card already well before booking, but figured it could work like my airline memberships and allow my membership number to the ticket retroactively :(