# How to use a "code avantage" discount code from the SNCF Voyageur program?

Tags: trains, tickets, france, loyalty-programs, high-speed-rail

Thanks to [this earlier question on the SNCF Voyageur program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27151/how-does-the-sncf-voyageur-program-work), I now know roughly how the program works, and I've signed up for it. Despite some issues with [previously bought tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/can-i-earn-sncf-voyager-points-for-a-booking-made-without-the-membership-number), I've managed to credit some TGV journeys to the program.

On logging into my account today, I notice that there seems to be a discount available for me to use:

[image: avantages]

It looks like I have a €5 discount available to use in the next few days before it expires. (Sadly I didn't notice it before). However, I can't for the life of me work out where to enter the code when booking a TGV ticket to take advantage of the discount.

So, does anyone know how/where you go about booking a discounted ticket using a "code avantage" shown in your SNCF Voyageur account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [voyages-sncf](http://www.voyages-sncf.com), the standard booking tool does not provide a field for your "Code Avantage". However, if you go for [advanced search](http://en.voyages-sncf.com/en/train-ticket), you will find, in the section for the passenger details, a "Promotional Code" field appearing.

[image: Booking a train trip]

I know it is not straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [voyages-sncf](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/billet-train) webpage, you'll see there's a field called `Code avantage`. Just type your code in, and the associated discount should be applied.

[image]

Comment: Ah ha! If you go to the homepage, it has all those boxes *except* the Code Avantage one. The link you've given has a different form with the space for it, which is what I'd missed, thanks!